# Import birthdays of friends from Facebook into Google Calendar?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar

Is there an easy way to import birthdays from my friends in Facebook into my calendar in Google?

Bonus points if it's possible to keep the birthday events automatically in sync (e.g. when I add new friends on Facebook, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign in to Facebook and go to your [Birthday Events](http://www.facebook.com/events/birthdays/). Clicking on the button with the magnifying glass, you will see an option to “Export Birthdays...”

The Export Birthdays dialog will give you a URL which you can then add to Google Calendars, iCal, Outlook or whatever your favourite calendar application is.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm glad Facebook finally implemented this feature. Just imported my birthday calendars into Google and it seems to be working great.

Comment: Good to know :) First thing I did after the import was to activate the SMS notifications but they got annoying really fast. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Try fbCal.  http://www.fbcal.com/  It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry but no, it doesn't seem to work. I even tried to download the `.ics` file they provide, but it only contains information about 1 (one!) of my contants.

Comment: Hmm - it's been quite reliable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [birthdayblob.com](http://birthdayblob.com)

Comment: Not terribly effective, you have to individually add contacts; one bye one. And it doesn't seem to sync. Though, it seems like a step in the right direction.